# wkhtmltopdf doesn't stretch div to bottom of page

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I have written some HTML that when converted to a PDF by wkhtmltopdf, creates 2 pages, each with two divs one above the other. I would like the bottom div to stretch to the bottom of each page. I haven't used a separate footer file, because the bottom div on each page needs to be able to contain different content.

I've simplified the HTML as much as possible, as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
            body {
                margin: 0;
                min-height: 100vh;
                height:100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            #top {
                height: 50px;
                background: yellow;
            }
            #bottom {
                background: lightgrey;
                flex: 1;
                height:100%;
                min-height:100%;
            }
            .break-after {
               page-break-after: always;
            }                
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top"><span>Page 1 header</span></div>
        <div id="bottom"><span>Page 1 content area - should extend to the bottom of the page</span></div>
        <div class="break-after"></div>
        <div id="top"><span>Page 2 header</span></div>
        <div id="bottom"><span>Page 2 content area - should extend to the bottom of the page</span></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Running this HTML through wkhtmltopdf doesn't produce the desired output (see the attached screenshots) I want the light blue div to stretch to the bottom of the page. I'm using version 0.12.6 (with patched qt).

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Do you know how to get the bottom div to stretch to the bottom of each page in the pdf output?